# Basic read of json fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's very simple. I have 2 selects. When the user selects the category, it will appear another select with a subcategory.

The problem is that subcategory select is always empty.

Category JSON (vm.categories):

```
[  
   {  
      "doctype":"1120",
      "description":"bla bla",
      "subcategories":[  
         {  
            "@id":1,
            "subcategory":"1",
            "description":"New Offer",
            "templates":[  
               {  
                  "template":"12",
                  "description":"asfafasga",
                  "deliveryChannels":[  

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "@id":2,
            "subcategory":"2",
            "description":"New Offer",
            "templates":[  
               {  
                  "template":"1121",
                  "description":"asfag",
                  "deliveryChannels":[  
                     {  
                        "deliveryType":"4",
                        "description":"Test"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <!-- Categories -->
        <label for="category-select"><b>Category&nbsp;</b></label>
        <select name="category-select" ng-model="vm.selectedCategory" required>
            <option value="" disabled>--- Please select a category ---</option> <!-- not selected / blank option -->
            <option value="{{category}}"
                    ng-repeat="category in vm.categories">
             {{category.description}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <!-- Sub Categories -->
        <label ng-show="vm.selectedCategory" for="subcategory-select"><b>Sub-Category&nbsp;</b></label>
        <select name="subcategory-select"
                ng-show="vm.selectedCategory"
                ng-model="vm.selectedSubCategory">
            <option value="" disabled>--- Please select a sub-category ---</option> <!-- not selected / blank option -->
            <option value="{{subCategory}}" 
                    ng-repeat="subCategory in vm.selectedCategory.subcategories">
                {{subCategory.description}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea why this is happening? Somehow I can't read the subcategories array from the selected category

EDIT: If I put   `<span>{{vm.selectedCategory}}</span>` in my html, it shows the json above. but if I put   `<span>{{vm.selectedCategory.subcategories}}</span>`   it's null

Another edit: Even `<span>{{vm.selectedCategory.doctype}}</span>`  is null

Comment: Where do you bind `selectedCategory` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your selected value is not evaluated as object but as string. To handle this issue you can:

You can either convert selected string to object with ng-change directive on first select and the following function

```
$scope.convert = function(){
    $scope.vm.selectedCategory = angular.fromJson($scope.vm.selectedCategory)
}
```

or use ng-options

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" ng-options="category.description for category in data" ng-model="vm.selectedCategory">
</select>
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/L7iIKntaO8jJJRNaXUPb?p=preview)**

Comment: but I get the JSON from an API with $http.get. Why is it not json?

Comment: It is json but as I mentioned in answer it is evaluated as string, try ng-options.

Comment: in my controller `vm.categories[0].subcategories` works well

Comment: but I still wanted to show the disabled Please Select option

Comment: You can show it just add the same code (<option value="" disabled>--- Please select a sub-category ---</option> ) inside your new select

Answer (score 0):

To make a working demo, had to simplify `vm.[namedVariables]` into simple variables: kindly check below

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedCategory = '';

  $scope.categories = [{
    "doctype": "1120",
    "description": "bla bla",
    "subcategories": [{
        "@id": 1,
        "subcategory": "1",
        "description": "New Offer",
        "templates": [{
          "template": "12",
          "description": "asfafasga",
          "deliveryChannels": [

          ]
        }]
      },
      {
        "@id": 2,
        "subcategory": "2",
        "description": "New Offer2",
        "templates": [{
          "template": "1121",
          "description": "asfag",
          "deliveryChannels": [{
            "deliveryType": "4",
            "description": "Test"
          }]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }];

  /*
  for(var i=0; i<$scope.profiles.length; i++){
    console.log($scope.profiles[0].TravelerExtended);
    console.log($scope.profiles[0].TravelerExtended.ExtendedInt_1);
  }
  */

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat='item in categories'>
    {{item.description}}
    <div ng-repeat='subC in item.subcategories'>
      {{subC.subcategory}} - {{subC.description}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr/>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <!-- Categories -->
      <label for="category-select"><b>Category&nbsp;</b></label>
      <select name="category-select" ng-model="selectedCategory" required>
        <option value="" disabled>--- Please select a category ---</option>
        <!-- not selected / blank option -->
        <option value="{{category.doctype}}" ng-repeat="category in categories">{{category.description}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <!-- Sub Categories -->
      <label ng-show="selectedCategory" for="subcategory-select"><b>Sub-Category&nbsp;</b></label>
     
     <ng-container ng-repeat="item in categories">
     <!--
     <p>(1) {{selectedCategory}} </p>
     <p>(2) {{item.doctype}} </p>
     -->
     <select name="subcategory-select" ng-show="selectedCategory == item.doctype" ng-model="vm.selectedSubCategory">
        <option value="" disabled>--- Please select a sub-category ---</option>
        <!-- not selected / blank option -->
        <option value="{{subCategory}}" ng-repeat="subCategory in item.subcategories">
          {{subCategory.description}}</option>
      </select>
      
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: why do I need all that? My implementation should work

Comment: you needed to have nested `ng-repeat` - this is what i did if you look closely... the top section (before `<hr />`) in HTML was just to show how nested ng-repeat give you all combinations

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `value` attribute with interpolation, use the `ng-value` directive:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <!-- Categories -->
        <label for="category-select"><b>Category&nbsp;</b></label>
        <select name="category-select" ng-model="vm.selectedCategory" required>
            <option value="" disabled>--- Please select a category ---</option> <!-- not selected / blank option -->
            ̶<̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶{̶{̶c̶a̶t̶e̶g̶o̶r̶y̶}̶}̶"̶
            <option ng-value="category"
                    ng-repeat="category in vm.categories">
             {{category.description}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The double curly bracket interpolation directive attempts to convert the `category` value to a string. This does not work well when the `category` value is an object.

For more information, see [AngularJS ng-value Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue).

---

> It says [Object Object] when I do `<span>{{vm.selectedCategory}}</span>` and i can't read the subcategories

Pipe the `vm.selectedCategory` into the json filter:

```
<span>{{ vm.selectedCategory | json }}</span>
```

This allows you to convert a JavaScript object into JSON string.

This filter is mostly useful for debugging. When using the double curly notation the binding is automatically converted to JSON.

For more information, see [AngularJS json Filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json).

Comment: Doesn't work with that. It says [Object Object] when I do <span>{{vm.selectedCategory}}</span> and i can't read the subcategories